# What's the difference between ojdbc6.jar and ojdbc16.jar

Tags: oracle, ojdbc

I have two oracle driver file.

ojdbc6.jar (2,713,510 byte) and ojdbc16.jar(2,111,338 byte)

What are they different? when I googled, some people say to use ojdbc6.jar. the other say use ojdbc16.jar

Even file size are slightly different so, I guess one is newer version.
Does someone know about this?

Thank you

Comment: Differences: file size, the character `1`, unique ID in the filesystem, etc., etc...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is that they are simply different versions of `ojdbc6.jar` (Oracle JDBC drivers compiled for Java 6). The file sizes on [Oracle's site](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-112010-090769.html) suggests that this may be the case (they are close).

I'm guessing someone was used to using the `ojdbc14`/`ojdbc15` jars and renamed the jar for consistency-sake?

I'm thinking your `ojdbc6.jar` is the 11.2.0.3 version, and the `ojdbc16.jar` is the 11.2.0.2.0 (close file sizes).

You should be able to confirm this by looking in the jars' manifest files (they should have the version information).